# What is the smallest diameter ring a non-convex polyhedron can pass through in 3-space?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computer-science, polyhedra

The question is mostly in the title:

> What is the smallest diameter ring a non-convex polyhedron can pass through in 3-space?

Imagine I have some non-convex polyhedron $P$, and I would like to find the smallest diameter ring that it can pass through in 3-space, undergoing any necessary rotations as it does so.  Is there an efficient way to calculate $D_{ring}$?  Pressing my luck, can I find the set of rotations for $P$ as it passes through the ring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the "piano movers problem", also known as the motion planning problem, which has an enormous literature. Check out
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_planning

Answer (score 5):

Just a side remark on *convex* polyhedra: Each of the regular polyhedra except the cube can pass
through a circle of radius smaller than the smallest-radius cylinder circumscribing the polyhedron.
This is proved in Tudor Zamfirescu's delightful paper, "Convex polytopes passing through circles"
([PDF link](http://fmi.unibuc.ro/ro/teme_cercetare/cex06_gta/RaportareIV/PolyThroughCircles.pdf)). There is quite a nice (non-algorithmic) literature on this problem.

Comment: Zamfirescu has a light touch despite deep thoughts. :-)